# code navigation not working in vscode python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Switched to visualcode(Version: 1.53.1) recently for Python(2.7.5 is the interpreter). Set up remote-ssh(localclient - OSX and remote machine - CentOS 7) and i am able to write and execute code without issues. It's a pretty big code base and the directory structure looks like below. I tried opening both src/ and main/ but the "Go to Definition" or "Go to references" would not work - it just says "Nothing is found".

It works if its under the same directory for some cases - for example the reference and definition in d22 might only be listed when i am searching in d22 but that does not work always either.

src

- main

  - d1
  - d2

    - d22

Tried the following but nothing is helping:

- Uninstalled all extensions except standard Python extension
- Reinstalled Visual Code
- Have set {{fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288}} and reloaded the conf since it initially showed too many files error.
- Closed vscode and opened it multiple times.

I also want to know if we have something like Kite that will work over remote ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the extension you used is "Python for VSCode". In VS Code, the "Go to Definition" and "Go to references" functions are provided by the "[Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)" extension. It is recommended that you install it or try to reinstall it if you have already installed it.

for the methods in the module:

[image]

for custom methods:

before "Go to Definition":

[image]

after "Go to Definition":

[image]

For remote development using SSH in VS Code, you could refer to this docs: [Remote Development using SSH.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh)

Comment: I am sorry, i have already installed "Python" Extension . I just noticed that there is literally a "Python for Vscode" plugin. 

I have also set up the remote development and it works fine, thanks.

Comment: I meant to say that - Go to Navigation or references is not working - I have already installed Python Extension.

Comment: @user9763248  -Have you tried to disable the "Python for Vscode" extension? If it is a custom method, it needs to import the defined file.

Comment: Hmm... Reinstalling of Python extension is really helped...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved this problem, but as of now, for me, I had the same problem, but when I go check out the Python extension in VS Code, there is a warning that "code navigation is disabled in this workspace" when it is remote. It suggested that I need to install the same extension in the remote in order to enable that functionality, which I could do with one click. After that, it works fine.